# Periodically call a function in pygtk's main loop

Tags: python, pygtk

What's the pygtk equivalent for after method in tkinter?

I want to periodically call a function in the main loop.

What is the better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [gobject.timeout_add](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add):

```
import gobject
gobject.timeout_add(milliseconds, callback)
```

For example here is a progress bar that uses `timeout_add` to update the progress (`HScale`) value:

```
import gobject
import gtk

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,widget):
        self.val=0
        self.scale = gtk.HScale()
        self.scale.set_range(0, 100)
        self.scale.set_update_policy(gtk.UPDATE_CONTINUOUS)
        self.scale.set_value(self.val)
        widget.add(self.scale)
        gobject.timeout_add(100, self.timeout)
    def timeout(self):
        self.val +=1
        self.scale.set_value(self.val)
        return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    win = gtk.Window()
    win.set_default_size(300,50)
    win.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    bar=Bar(win)
    win.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the different between glib.timeout_add and gobject.timeout_add?

Comment: @houqp: They are the same function. `gobject` imports `timeout_add` from `glib`.

Comment: @pahnin: To stop the `timeout` function from getting called, have it return `False`. See [the docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add).

Comment: ya I did that but I thought may be there is a function to stop the timer like in javascript settimeout cleartimeout

Comment: Just what I was looking for? Can someone please mark this answer as correct?

Comment: I get "PyGIDeprecationWarning: GObject.timeout_add is deprecated; use GLib.timeout_add instead"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the new [Python GObject Introspection API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/), you should use [`GLib.timeout_add()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add).

Note that the documentation seems to be incorrect. It is actually:

```
timeout_add(interval, function, *user_data, **kwargs)
```

Here's an example. Note that `run` is a *callable* object, but it could be any ordinary function or method.

```
from gi.repository import GLib

class Runner:
    def __init__(self, num_times):
        self.num_times = num_times
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.count += 1
        print("Periodic timer [{}]: args={}".format(self.count, args))

        return self.count < self.num_times

run = Runner(5)

interval_ms = 1000
GLib.timeout_add(interval_ms, run, 'foo', 123)

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 glib_timeout.py 
Periodic timer [1]: args=('foo', 123)
Periodic timer [2]: args=('foo', 123)
Periodic timer [3]: args=('foo', 123)
Periodic timer [4]: args=('foo', 123)
Periodic timer [5]: args=('foo', 123)
<messages stop but main loop keeps running>
```

Answer (score 0):

or the simplest test code
// base on Jonathon Reinhart's answer

```py
from gi.repository import GLib

i = 0
def test1(*args):
    global i
    i+=1
    print('test1:', i, args)
    if i<3:
        return True # keep running
    else:
        return False # end timer

# call test1 every 1000ms, until it return False
GLib.timeout_add(1000, test1, 'foo', 123)

loop = GLib.MainLoop() # just for test without UI
loop.run()
```

outputs:

```
$ python3 ../test_gtk_timeout.py
test1: 1 ('foo', 123)
test1: 2 ('foo', 123)
test1: 3 ('foo', 123)
```