# How do I pause a loop with a button in PyGObject?

Tags: gtk, pygobject

I have a button that runs a loop and updates the window accordingly. I want another "pause" button that pauses this loop but it doesn't seem like I can do that while the loop is running. Perhaps threading is the solution (I tried GLib.timeout_add_seconds without success) - what is the easiest way to make this work?
I have attached my faulty code:

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class LoopButton(Gtk.Box):

    def __init__(self, GUI):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self)

        self.GUI = GUI
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.message = "1"

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Run")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click)
        self.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

    def on_click(self, widget):
        msg = int(self.message)
        while self.GUI.is_paused == False:
            self.GUI.restart_window(str(msg))
            msg += 1
            while Gtk.events_pending():
                Gtk.main_iteration()
            sleep(1)
        self.GUI.is_paused = True

class PauseButton(Gtk.Box):
    def __init__(self, GUI):
        Gtk.Box.__init__(self)

        self.GUI = GUI
        self.set_border_width(10)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Pause")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click)
        self.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

    def on_click(self, widget):
        self.GUI.is_paused = True


class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_paused = False
        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label("Default label")
        self.win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.start_window()

    def start_window(self):
        self.box.pack_start(LoopButton(self), True, True, 0)
        self.box.pack_start(PauseButton(self), True, True, 0)
        self.window_grid.add(self.box)
        self.window_grid.add(self.label)
        self.win.add(self.window_grid)
        self.win.show_all()

    def restart_window(self, label="Default label"):
        self.window_grid.destroy()
        self.window_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label)
        self.start_window()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916094/why-cant-i-have-a-loop-in-the-onclick-function-in-pygobject ?

Comment: What will your actual code be doing in the loop? The answer depends on that.

Comment: @jku No it's not. It's very similar and I modified that code but I asked how to pause the loop, something that the other question did not do

Comment: @andlabs Why does it matter? I don't think the answer should depend on what I am doing. If it is indeed relevant, I am using a package called graph-tool and I am creating a new graph and displaying it, among other widgets that depend on the graph. My actual code is somewhat complicated/difficult to understand so an answer to this question (how to pause a loop with a button) should answer my question for my actual code.

Comment: @Billjoe andlabs is asking because you cannot do long loops in the main GTK thread. What you should do instead depends on the type of task  the loop does. Usually it's possible to avoid the loop and use timeouts, idle handlers or asynchronous library calls instead. Sometimes you really need to use another thread to run the loop.

Comment: @jku I'm using graph-tool and I have a "step" function that steps through my data over time and refreshes the graph with the new data. My "run" function essentially calls my step function, sleeps for 2 seconds, and calls it again. I think I can probably use timeouts, if I understand it correctly. How do I do that? Essentially I want to call a function every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you really do in the loop there may be more necessary details, but below is an example of how looping is normally avoided in GLib/Gtk. The caveats of this method are: A) one iteration must be fast enough to not affect UI updates (a few milliseconds at most). B) The timing is not exact: the timeout function might not be called *exactly* 2 seconds after the previous call.

```
import gi
from gi.repository import GLib

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the UI here...

        # setup updates every two seconds
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(2, self.timeout_update)

    def timeout_update(self):
        # update your widgets here
        print ("Updating UI now...")

        # yes, we want to be called again
        return True
```

Comment: Perfect - this works now. I was trying to use timeout_add_seconds before also but I wasn't returning True, which made it not run properly.